# visual studio 2017 xaml visual designer hidden when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When debugging in Visual Studio 2017 it hides the xaml visual designer when opening a xaml document, showing only the xaml text. Is it still possible to show the visual designer when debugging?

I've just started using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. I was previously using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/178903/vs2017-hides-xaml-designer-when-debugging.html):

> "This is by design starting with 2017. We do not want people to interact with the designer while in a debugging session.", Charles Bissonnette [MSFT]

With the UI Debugging Tools for XAML your running application is the Designer.